# AngularJs Data Manipulation before display

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a simple table in which there are 2 columns: a) Name b) Country. Currently it works fine and displays name of the user and country.

Now I want to add a condition so that if the country is `Germany` then instead of Germany it should print `Europe` and if country is `Argentina` or `Brazil` it should print `South America`, for other countries it will remain same, for example `UK`, `Sweden` or any other country will be printed as it is.

My angular code is this ::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost/test/user_data.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And json data in my user-data.php file is this::

```
{
    "records":[
    {"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"},
    {"Name":"Ana Trujillo Emparedados","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"},
    {"Name":"Antonio Moreno Taquería","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"},
    {"Name":"Around the Horn","City":"London","Country":"UK"},
    {"Name":"B's Beverages","City":"London","Country":"UK"},
    {"Name":"Berglunds snabbköp","City":"Luleå","Country":"Sweden"},
    {"Name":"Blauer See Delikatessen","City":"Mannheim","Country":"Germany"},
    {"Name":"Blondel père et fils","City":"Strasbourg","Country":"France"},
    {"Name":"Bólido Comidas preparadas","City":"Madrid","Country":"Spain"},
    {"Name":"Bon app'","City":"Marseille","Country":"France"},
    {"Name":"Bottom-Dollar Marketse","City":"Tsawassen","Country":"Canada"},
    {"Name":"Cactus Comidas para llevar","City":"Buenos Aires","Country":"Argentina"},
    {"Name":"Centro comercial Moctezuma","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"},
    {"Name":"Chop-suey Chinese","City":"Bern","Country":"Switzerland"},
    {"Name":"Comércio Mineiro","City":"São Paulo","Country":"Brazil"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: how can I do this in services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous ways to achieve this in angular. (directives, functions, services, ng-if...etc.)

The cleanest in your case would be a custom filter:

```
.filter('countryFormat', function() {
    return function(input) {
        if (input != undefined) {
           //Your switch case here
           return 'South America'; // for example
        }
    }
});
```

And in the html:

```
<td>{{ x.Country | countryFormat }}</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should create a function inside your controller to check which country it is and should decide what to output

check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7opnzo2/)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.names =[
    {"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"},
    {"Name":"Ana Trujillo Emparedados","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"},
    {"Name":"Antonio Moreno Taquería","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"},
    {"Name":"Around the Horn","City":"London","Country":"UK"},
    {"Name":"B's Beverages","City":"London","Country":"UK"},
    {"Name":"Berglunds snabbköp","City":"Luleå","Country":"Sweden"},
    {"Name":"Blauer See Delikatessen","City":"Mannheim","Country":"Germany"},
    {"Name":"Blondel père et fils","City":"Strasbourg","Country":"France"},
    {"Name":"Bólido Comidas preparadas","City":"Madrid","Country":"Spain"},
    {"Name":"Bon app'","City":"Marseille","Country":"France"},
    {"Name":"Bottom-Dollar Marketse","City":"Tsawassen","Country":"Canada"},
    {"Name":"Cactus Comidas para llevar","City":"Buenos Aires","Country":"Argentina"},
    {"Name":"Centro comercial Moctezuma","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"},
    {"Name":"Chop-suey Chinese","City":"Bern","Country":"Switzerland"},
    {"Name":"Comércio Mineiro","City":"São Paulo","Country":"Brazil"}
    ]

    $scope.getCountry = function(country) {
    if(country === 'Germany'){
    return 'EU'
    } else {
    return country
    }
    }

});
```

and use it in html like below

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ getCountry(x.Country) }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

inside td of name

```
<td><div ng-if="x.name=="Germany">Europe</div><div ng-if="x.name=="argentina||brazil">south america</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ng-switch also

```
 <td ng-switch on="x.Country">
        <div ng-switch-when="Germany ">Europe </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="Argentina">South America</div>
         <div ng-switch-when="Brazil ">South America</div>
         <div ng-switch-when="Brazil ">South America</div>
         <div ng-switch-default>{{x.Country}}</div>
      </td>
```

for refrence https://plnkr.co/edit/OFWhePEJEuHSrBR3zW9i

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
            <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
                <td ng-hide="(x.Country == 'Argentina' || x.Country == 'Brazil' || x.Country == 'Germany')">{{ x.Country }}</td>
                <td ng-show="x.Country=='Germany'">Europe</td>
                <td ng-show="x.Country == 'Argentina' || x.Country == 'Brazil'">South America</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td ng-if = "x.Country === 'Germany'">Europe</td>
    <td ng-if = "x.Country === 'Argentina'|| x.Country ==='Brazil'">South America</td>
    <td ng-if = "x.Country !== 'Argentina' || x.Country !== 'Brazil' || x.Country !== 'Germany'">{{x.Country}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's always better to add an explanation to the code you're posting as an answer, so that it will helps visitors understand why this is a good answer.